# jest dom is not updating after element.innerText is set imperatively

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, lwc-jest

I am testing a component that renders a table. Each row of the table body has a column that contains a button, when the button is pressed a javascript handler modifies the cell by setting the `innerText` imperatively.

```html
<table class="
    slds-table
    slds-table_cell-buffer
    slds-table_bordered
    slds-table_fixed-layout
    slds-table_striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
            <th class="" scope="col">Locker</th>
            <th scope="col">Locker Combination</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template for:each={lockers} for:item="locker">
            <tr key={locker.index}>
                <td class="slds-cell-wrap">{locker.locker}</td>
                <td class="slds-cell-wrap">
                    <span data-index={locker.index}>********</span>
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:preview" size="x-small" data-index={locker.index}
                        onclick={toggleLockerCombination}>
                    </lightning-icon>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
toggleLockerCombination(event) {
    const index = event.currentTarget.dataset.index;
    const hidden = event.currentTarget.iconName === 'utility:preview';
    const combinationSpan = this.template.querySelector(`span[data-index="${index}"]`);
    if (hidden) {
        const combination = this.lockers[index].combination;
        combinationSpan.innerText = combination;
        event.currentTarget.iconName = 'utility:hide';
    } else {
        combinationSpan.innerText = '********';
        event.currentTarget.iconName = 'utility:preview';
    }
}
```

When I test this, the dom does not update and my jest tests do not pass.

```html
<table class=\"slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_fixed-layout
    slds-table_striped\">
    <thead>
        <tr class=\"slds-line-height_reset\">
            <th scope=\"col\">Locker</th>
            <th scope=\"col\">Combination</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class=\"slds-cell-wrap\">A1</td>
            <td class=\"slds-cell-wrap\"><span data-index=\"0\">********</span>
                <lightning-icon data-index=\"0\"></lightning-icon>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=\"slds-cell-wrap\">A2</td>
            <td class=\"slds-cell-wrap\"><span data-index=\"1\">********</span>
                <lightning-icon data-index=\"1\"></lightning-icon>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
const toggle = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('lightning-icon[data-index="0"]');
toggle.click();
await flushPromises();

// then
await waitFor(() => {
    const combination1Cell = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('span[data-index="0"]');
    const combination2Cell = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('span[data-index="1"]');
    expect(combination1Cell.textContent).toBe(MOCK_LOCKERS[0].combination);
    expect(combination2Cell.textContent).toBe('********');
});
```

I have confirmed the javascript handler is called and sets the `innerText` of the correct span when I step through debug, but the element's dom does not update in the test.

I've also confirmed the dom in the browser updates the span's inner text and shows the update, it's just not working in the test.

How can I get the jest dom to update when I set the innerText imperatively?

Comment: Did you already tried adding log statements in the test to verify you get the correct element with query selector and to check its current textContent? --> console.log(combination1Cell.textContent)

Comment: Additionally instead of the await logic you currently implemented, you could also try to add the following line in your test between "updating the innerText" and "checking it's current innerText" to make sure the LWC DOM was updated already: await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 0));